# sqlalchemy not saving association

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a script for injecting data into my sqlalchemy database and it fails to save an association for unknown reasons. It doesn't give an error or bug it just doesn't save anything. It does the same thing in the console.

```
from api import create_app, models, db

app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()

Type = models.Type
TypeSettings = models.TypeSettings

ts1 = TypeSettings(isHome=True, layoutType='classic', productCard='neon')
t1 = Type(name='Grocery', slug='grocery', icon='FruitsVegetable', settings=ts1)
db.session.add(t1, ts1)
db.session.commit()
```

Here is a console from Flask Shell showing it does not save the association.

```
>>> db.session.scalars(Language.select()).all()[0]
<api.models.Language object at 0x0000020D4213E650>
>>> db.session.scalars(Language.select()).all()[0].language
'en'
>>> t1=db.session.scalars(Type.select()).all()[0]
>>> ts1=db.session.scalars(TypeSettings.select()).all()[0]
>>> t1.settings #shows null which makes sense because it hasn't been set
>>> t1.settings=ts1
>>> t1.settings #appears to have saved properly but not yet committed
<api.models.TypeSettings object at 0x0000020D421DB460>
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> t1.settings #shows null after commit...
```

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1 and SQLAlchemy==1.4.32

Here is my shell context so you know how it is built

```
    # define the shell context
    @app.shell_context_processor
    def shell_context():  # pragma: no cover
        ctx = {'db': db}
        for attr in dir(models):
            model = getattr(models, attr)
            if hasattr(model, '__bases__') and \
                    db.Model in getattr(model, '__bases__'):
                ctx[attr] = model
        return ctx
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to debug your code from a distance, but I think you need to replace

```
db.session.add(t1, ts1)
```

with

```
db.session.add_all([t1, ts1])
```

to add multiple elements.

Comment: I tried that and it gave an error <code>sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.list' is not mapped</code>.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried .add(t1) and .add(ts1) in two separate lines?

Comment: In some cases add_all only works if every element in the list is of the same type.

Comment: third suggestion would be to use a context like this `with db.session() as sess: sess.add(ts) sess.add(ts1) sess.commit()` - i‘ll format this once i get home

Comment: I found the issue. I had settings mapped as a 1to1 from Type to TypeSettings and used uselist=False to map the 1 to many side as 1 to one. Apparently setting lazy='noload' interferes with uselist so I removed it and now it all works.